# Unknown column 'dd' in 'field list' while using DATE_FORMAT in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am fetching date form data base. So i have to change the date format.
So i have used `DATE_FORMAT` but it gives me the error:

> **Unknown column 'dd' in 'field list'**

How can I format the Date while fetching the data form database.

Date formate in datebase: **`YYYY-mm-dd`**
Wanted Date Formate     : **`dd-mm-YYYY`**

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT
(date_add(CURDATE(), interval (credit_validity_duration*30) day), dd-mm-YYYY) as max_credit_valid_date, 
date_add(CURDATE(), interval (app_d_validity_duration*30) day) as max_add_d_validity_date, 
date_add(CURDATE(), interval add_b_validity_duration day) as add_b_validity_duration, 
,`id` FROM `app_table` WHERE `user` = 'A'
```

This is the Codeigniter Active record query:

```
$this->db->select( 
                DATE_FORMAT(date_add(CURDATE(), interval (credit_validity_duration*30) day), dd-mm-YYYY) as max_credit_valid_date, 
                date_add(CURDATE(), interval (app_d_validity_duration*30) day) as max_add_d_validity_date, 
                date_add(CURDATE(), interval bonus_validity_duration day) as bonus_validity_duration, 
                ,id
            );
$this->db->from('app_table');   
$this->db->where('user', "A" );
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: Try to insert your dd-mm-YYYY inside quote (`"` or `'`)

Comment: I have highlighted it @HimanshuUpadhyay

Comment: Tried that not working both  single and dubble @Nawin

Comment: @always-a-learner, check my query written in my answer.

Comment: Try double quote. I am sure about it.

Comment: @ankitsuthar  Your comment is the key sir thanks to you also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DATE_FORMAT(date_add(CURDATE(), interval (credit_validity_duration*30) day), "%d-%m-%Y")
```

use the format like this and the date should be inside `qoutes`

Comment: Message: syntax error, unexpected '%'  Tried that bro.

Answer (score 1):

Update your query like this:

```
$this->db->select( 
                'DATE_FORMAT(date_add(CURDATE(), interval (credit_validity_duration*30) day), "%d-%m-%Y") as max_credit_valid_date, 
                date_add(CURDATE(), interval (app_d_validity_duration*30) day) as max_add_d_validity_date, 
                date_add(CURDATE(), interval bonus_validity_duration day) as bonus_validity_duration, 
                ,id'
            );
$this->db->from('app_table');   
$this->db->where('user', "A" );
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: What did you change in your answer? It is not an answer..It is just comment

Comment: I changed format string as well as put it into quotes.

Comment: It is not an answer You can tell that into comment Not need to post that same question with that quetes

Comment: **Error** : Message: syntax error, unexpected '%' @HimanshuUpadhyay

Comment: Thanks for the help sir, 1 up for the help sir. Thank again.